# convert datatype from object to integer

Tags: python, dataframe, types, integer, varchar

I'm trying to convert the target column to `INT` but when I'm execute there is the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"3,182.00"'
```

code:

```
df1['tranq'] = df1['tranq'].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Danielhab:

Convert first the value into float:

```
>>> int("3182.00")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3182.00'

>>> int(float("3182.00"))
3182
```

Change your cast of pandas dataframe to float.